# Mailto command causing a page redirect in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mailto

I am facing a weird issue on my web page.

I have an anchor tag which is basically for opening a mail application as below:

```
<a href="mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=ayx%20pqr">Contact us</a>
```

I am also calling a function on unload event in  as below:

```
<body onunload="JavaScript:ABC('value');">
```

When I click "Contact us" on the web page, outlook mail item will open and the page is getting redirected to "mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=ayx%20pqr" in IE8

This works fine in Google Chrome

FYI... I am using IE8 and Win 7. It's a ".htm" page

However, other pages that don't call any javascript on unload are working perfectly fine as expected.

Kindly suggest me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
G

Comment: can you post your javascript function ?

Comment: It does not matter what code I have inside my js function. The issue exists even when I just have an alert function inside my js function.<body onunload="JavaScript:alert('hi');">

Comment: Please see the following thread for more information on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674527/mailto-causing-a-blank-page-in-ie8-when-used-with-dojo In short, enabling "Protected Mode" in the security zone seems to fix the problem.